# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType - - -

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I'm getting an error with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
return cls._handle_exception(e)
File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 285, in _handle_exception
if exception.html in view.arch:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not NoneType - - -
```

This is my python file (report_xlsx module in odoo):

```
from odoo import models


class DailyTasksXLS(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.hr_daily_task.report_daily_task_xls'
    _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'

    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, lines):
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 12, 'align': 'vcenter', })
        for line in lines.work_ids:
            sheet.write(l, 0, line.name, format2)
            sheet.write(l, 1, line.description, format2)
            sheet.write(l, 2, line.unit_amount, format2)
            l = l+1
            total_hours = total_hours + line.unit_amount
            total_col = l
```

How to solve this?

Comment: is there any other code? because error is in `if exception.html in view.arch:` line because of `exception.html` is of `NoneType`

Comment: Kindly see this link, all code of python file was here:

https://notepad.link/rehfz

I've also tried to comment the template's body in xml but I still getting the error so probably the error is around the python file but still I'm not sure.